# Entity Framework - Capitalizing first property name letter

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

In general, I tend to name my sql database columns using the following camel case convention:

camelCase (notice that the first letter is in lower case).

But when working with C#, I like to name my object's public properties in the following convention:

PascalCase (notice the first is in uppwer case).

Entity Framework's default behaviour is to name the created classes' properties to match their relative column names as they are in the database.

Is there any property in the project/solution level which can be changed in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it dbFirst approch ryt ?

Comment: I have tried renaming the tables on the ADO.NET entity data model designer (double click .edmx file) but if I rename the tables in there then The methods also get renames. For example if I rename the table `customer` to `Customer` then the method `AddTocustomers` get's renamed to `AddToCustomers1` why does visual studio places a 1?

Comment: You need to only modify the property names ryt ?

Answer (score 16):

Yes there is. Here you can see the full example:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Properties().Configure(c =>
            {
                var name = c.ClrPropertyInfo.Name;
                var newName = char.ToLower(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
                c.HasColumnName(newName);
            });
        }

        public MyDbCondenxt(string cs) : base(cs)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new MyDbContext ("DefaultConnection");
            context.MyModels.Add(new MyModel{SomeText = "hello"});
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeText { get; set; }
    }


}
```

The property name is "SomeText" and the column name is "someText".

Comment: I'm using EF Core 2.0.0 and it seems `modelBuilder.Properties()` doesn't exist. Are there any other solutions for EF Core?

Comment: I found my answer here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5159#issuecomment-256300665

Answer (score 4):

I dont know of a solution level but you can set an attribute on your entity

```
[Table("myEntity")]
public class MyEntity{}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I'm looking for something which will affect the entire model since it's kind of a hassle to go through the entire set of properties for each class.

Answer (score 2):

Achieving this is not impossible, but it's not going to be easy.  Some of it depends which type of ef model you're working with, either code first or database/model first (they are similar in this regard), or if you're using the old ObjectContext based methods.

In general, EF uses T4 templating to create the actual classes and models in all but code first, so it's possible to edit the T4 templates and generate whatever you want, such as automatically generating properties with PascalCasing.

If you're using Code first (which doesn't really require that you code first, it's a terrible name) then you can use the Entity Framework power tools to reverse engineer your database to code first models, and again it uses T4 to do this.

If you're using actual code first (ie you create your models and generate your database from the model), then it may not be possible in the existing EF5 or lower.  EF6 (currently in alpha) has something known as custom conventions that you could probably use for this, but it's still a long way from production quality.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I also had that kind of problem. So I simply write a tool in c# to rename the existing edmx file and then after the renaming each section of edmx file,Next using T4 template regenerate the Poco classes. It resolved my problem. It generates the expected POCO classes with Camel Case properties. Basically in the edmx we have 3 layers. So we need to modify 2 layers of them.

- MappingsSection
- ConceptualModelsSection

Please find the following class to do that.

```
namespace Edmx_Manager_V1._0
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Xml;

    public static class RenameManager
    {
        public static XmlDocument Document = new XmlDocument();
        public static string FilePath;
        public static XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr;

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the conceptual models section.
        /// </summary>
        public static void UpdateConceptualModelsSection()
        {

            ///////////////////////update ConceptualModels section//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            XmlNodeList Schema = Document.SelectNodes("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:ConceptualModels/edm:Schema", nsmgr);

            XmlNode SchemaNode = Schema[0];
            XmlElement SchemaNodeXmlElement = SchemaNode as XmlElement;

            //get all EntitySet nodes under  EntityContainer node
            XmlNodeList EntitySetlist = SchemaNodeXmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("EntitySet");

            //get all EntityType nodes under  SchemaNode
            XmlNodeList EntityTypelist = SchemaNodeXmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("EntityType");

            foreach (XmlNode EntityTypenode in EntityTypelist)
            {

                //to call GetElementsByTagName we need XmlElement object
                XmlElement EntityTypenodeelement = EntityTypenode as XmlElement;

                //get all PropertyRef nodes under  EntityType node
                XmlNodeList PropertyReflist = EntityTypenodeelement.GetElementsByTagName("PropertyRef");

                foreach (XmlNode PropertyRefnode in PropertyReflist)
                {
                    //update name attribute of Key/PropertyRef nodes
                    XmlAttribute PropertyRef_nameAttribute = PropertyRefnode.Attributes["Name"];
                    PropertyRef_nameAttribute.Value = UppercaseFirst(PropertyRef_nameAttribute.Value);
                }

                //get all Property nodes under  EntityType node
                XmlNodeList Propertylist = EntityTypenodeelement.GetElementsByTagName("Property");

                foreach (XmlNode Propertynode in Propertylist)
                {
                    //update name attribute of PropertyRef nodes
                    XmlAttribute Property_nameAttribute = Propertynode.Attributes["Name"];
                    Property_nameAttribute.Value = UppercaseFirst(Property_nameAttribute.Value);
                }

                //get all NavigationProperty nodes under  EntityType node
                XmlNodeList NavigationPropertylist = EntityTypenodeelement.GetElementsByTagName("NavigationProperty");

                foreach (XmlNode NavigationPropertynode in NavigationPropertylist)
                {
                    //update name attribute of NavigationProperty nodes
                    XmlAttribute NavigationPropertynode_nameAttribute = NavigationPropertynode.Attributes["Name"];
                    NavigationPropertynode_nameAttribute.Value = UppercaseFirst(NavigationPropertynode_nameAttribute.Value) + "s";// we append "s" for nav properties
                }
            }

            //get  Association node under  Schema node
            XmlNodeList Associationlist = SchemaNodeXmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("Association");

            //get all Association nodes and process
            foreach (XmlNode AssociationNode in Associationlist)
            {
                if (AssociationNode != null)
                {
                    XmlElement AssociationNodeXmlElement = AssociationNode as XmlElement;
                    //get all end nodes under Association
                    XmlNodeList EndNodelist2 = AssociationNodeXmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("End");

                    //get all PropertyRef nodes under Association
                    XmlNodeList PropertyReflist2 = AssociationNodeXmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("PropertyRef");

                    foreach (XmlNode PropertyRefNode2 in PropertyReflist2)
                    {
                        //update Type attribute
                        XmlAttribute PropertyRefNode2Attribute = PropertyRefNode2.Attributes["Name"];
                        PropertyRefNode2Attribute.Value = UppercaseFirst(PropertyRefNode2Attribute.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("ConceptualModelSection updated..");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the mappings section.
        /// </summary>
        public static void UpdateMappingsSection()
        {

            ///////////////////////update edmx:Mappings section//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            XmlNodeList EntityContainerMapping = Document.SelectNodes("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:Mappings/cs:Mapping", nsmgr);
            XmlNode EntityContainerMapping_Node = EntityContainerMapping[0];
            XmlElement EntityContainerMappingNode_XmlElement = EntityContainerMapping_Node as XmlElement;

            // update name attribute of all EntitySetMapping nodes

            //get all EntitySetMapping nodes
            XmlNodeList EntitySetMappinglist = EntityContainerMappingNode_XmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("EntitySetMapping");

            //get all EntityTypeMapping nodes
            XmlNodeList EntityTypeMappinglist = EntityContainerMappingNode_XmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("EntityTypeMapping");

            //get all ScalarProperty nodes
            XmlNodeList ScalarPropertyist = EntityContainerMappingNode_XmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("ScalarProperty");

            foreach (XmlNode ScalarPropertyNode in ScalarPropertyist)
            {
                XmlAttribute nameAttribute = ScalarPropertyNode.Attributes["Name"];
                nameAttribute.Value = UppercaseFirst(nameAttribute.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("MappingSection updated..");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uppercases the first.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string UppercaseFirst(string name)
        {

            return char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);

        }
    }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
            RenameManager.FilePath = @"C:\Users\therath\testApp\Model1.edmx";
            // Path of edmx file in the your solution
            RenameManager.Document.Load(@RenameManager.FilePath);
            RenameManager.nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(RenameManager.Document.NameTable);
            RenameManager.nsmgr.AddNamespace("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx");
            RenameManager.nsmgr.AddNamespace("edm", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm");
            //nsmgr.AddNamespace("ssdl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl");
            RenameManager.nsmgr.AddNamespace("cs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs");

            try
            {
                RenameManager.UpdateConceptualModelsSection();
                RenameManager.UpdateMappingsSection();
                RenameManager.Document.Save(@RenameManager.FilePath);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
```

If you generate the edmx again you may need to run this tool again.

Answer (score 1):

there are ways to do that , some of are already pointed out by others..

i found one class which does that ...

```
namespace System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions
{
  /// <summary>
 /// Convention to convert any data types that were explicitly specified, via data     annotations or <see cref="T:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder"/> API,
 ///                 to be lower case. The default SqlClient provider is case   sensitive and requires data types to be lower case. This convention 
///                 allows the <see   cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ColumnAttrbiute"/> and <see cref="T:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder"/> API to be case insensitive.
/// 
/// </summary>
public sealed class ColumnTypeCasingConvention : IDbConvention<DbTableColumnMetadata>,   IConvention
{
  internal ColumnTypeCasingConvention()
{
}

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1308:NormalizeStringsToUppercase")]
void IDbConvention<DbTableColumnMetadata>.Apply(DbTableColumnMetadata tableColumn, DbDatabaseMetadata database)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tableColumn.TypeName))
    return;
  tableColumn.TypeName = tableColumn.TypeName.ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

}
}

explicit implementation of idbconvertion does that thing which you can implement

another one is to

go to solution => and find folder obj/debug/edmxresourcestoembed

there are three files db.csdl , db.msl , db.ssdl
edit msl file => you 'll see mapping for each table like as under.

```
 <EntitySetMapping Name="Address">
  <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(AdventureWorksLTModel.Address)">
    <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Address">
      <ScalarProperty Name="AddressID" ColumnName="AddressID" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="AddressLine1" ColumnName="AddressLine1" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="AddressLine2" ColumnName="AddressLine2" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="City" ColumnName="City" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="StateProvince" ColumnName="StateProvince" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="CountryRegion" ColumnName="CountryRegion" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="PostalCode" ColumnName="PostalCode" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="rowguid" ColumnName="rowguid" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="ModifiedDate" ColumnName="ModifiedDate" />
    </MappingFragment>
  </EntityTypeMapping>
</EntitySetMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the .edmx file. Just click on the property name and rename it to camel case and the same will be reflected whenever you try to access it using the object.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm looking for something which will affect the entire model since it's kind of a hassle to go through the entire set of properties for each class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tools like
http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/

With the inbuild EDMX desinger this isnt possible, since the "update from database" routine doesnt have such a function.

Answer (score 0):

The class code is generated from a T4 template. Depending on your configuration, this may already be in your project, or the EDMX may be using a built-in one, in which case you would need to add your own and set the "code generation strategy" to "None" in the EDMX properties (through the model browser). From this file it is fairly easy to find and modify the class and property name generation.

The default is calling an `Escape` function, which is defined in include files at *"IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/Entity Framework Tools/Templates/Includes"* under the Visual Studio folder, and ultimately just calls [CreateEscapedIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.createescapedidentifier.aspx). Simply call this with the capitalized version of the string.

FYI: These names are coming from the [EntityType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.entitytype.aspx) and [NavigationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.navigationproperty.aspx) objects as defined in the EDMX, not directly from the database. If you are using the "generate from database" feature for the EDMX, the names may have already gone through a transformation and the original table names are not retained in the model. This probably won't be an issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can edit the names in the edmx actually, but everytime you refresh from database it's back to doing it again.

The only viable approach when using edmx type datatypes is to have the correct names (with capital letters) in the tables of the database or it will be to tedious.

You can of cause use link to sql instead,  in which case you define your data classes and just supply a name property. But be warned this approach is significantly more manual and is being aborted most places because it requires much more thinking to set up that edmx autogeneration which is a click, click, next approach.

So yes you can edit the names in the edmx, but consider abandoning your camelCasing for tables instead, in hommage to edmx which saves you for a ton on work in return, or your .net autogenerated proxy classes will look wierd, as you know.