# Entity Framework 6 Model-First does not capitalize entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, c#-6.0

Is there a way to force **EF6** to capitalize the generated entities in a Model-First approach? The generated table names are all singular lower case.

So, I have my users persisted on a table with the name `user` and I want my corresponding entity named as `Users`.

I'm using C# 6 with EF6 and `TablePerTypeStrategy.xaml`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505088/entity-framework-capitalizing-first-property-name-letter