# Using T4 template to force PascalCase (TitleCase) for entities in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, t4

Turns out, simply modifying the default T4 template was actually really easy. Inside `GetTypeName` there is a `is StructuralType` check which handles all non-primitive types. That pretty well fixed the majority of my issues. Then it was just a matter of `Ctrl-F` for keywords. My frustration was just getting the best of me when I originally posted this question.

--

I have been provided with a database that has all table names and column names in snake_case. The database cannot be changed. I am hoping to use the power of T4 templates to auto-generate all classes, members, properties, navigation properties, etc. in PascalCase (TitleCase).

So far, I am getting decently close, but I am starting to get stuck.

```
namespace PokeDB
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ability
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ability()
        {
            this.ability_changelog = new HashSet<ability_changelog>();
            this.ability_flavor_text = new HashSet<ability_flavor_text>();
            this.ability_names = new HashSet<ability_names>();
            this.ability_prose = new HashSet<ability_prose>();
            this.conquest_pokemon_abilities = new HashSet<conquest_pokemon_abilities>();
            this.pokemon_abilities = new HashSet<pokemon_abilities>();
        }

        public long id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public long generation_id { get; set; }
        public bool is_main_series { get; set; }

        public virtual generation Generation { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AbilityChangelog> AbilityChangelog { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AbilityFlavorText> AbilityFlavorText { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AbilityNames> AbilityNames { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AbilityProse> AbilityProse { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ConquestPokemonAbilities> ConquestPokemonAbilities { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonAbilities> PokemonAbilities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As shown above, I have gotten the class name, the navigation property names, some of the navigation property return values, and the file name. Where I am getting stuck is the Constructor name, Constructor assignments, Properties, and the remainder of the navigation properties return values.

Right now, I am just manually replacing all references of the string with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(string).Replace("_", "")`.

For Example, for the class name:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }
```

Changed To:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(_code.Escape(entity)).Replace("_", ""),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }
```

It has been a long and tedious process, but it's better than absolutely nothing. I was hoping that you guys might have some further advice for me, or a bit of a cleaner solution? This is my first time using any type of custom T4 template. It feels like I should be able to knock some of these out with one fell swoop in some of the `TypeManager` methods. I'm just not entirely sure where.

I have found a couple StackOverflow questions and a couple blog posts about using T4 templates to do this, but unfortunately the templates were never shared.

Even if it isn't necessarily a perfect solution, I would appreciate any amount of guidance.

---

```
using System.Linq;

namespace PokeDB
{
    public class ConsoleDriver
    {
        public static readonly PokeDBContainer PokeDB = new PokeDBContainer();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(PokeDB.Pokemon);
            var x = PokeDB.Pokemon.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the current test driver that I have written to test out my DBContext. The very first line fails with a The following message: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll Additional information: The entity type Pokemon is not part of the model for the current context.`

```
namespace PokeDB
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("pokemon")]
    public partial class Pokemon
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Pokemon()
        {
            this.Encounters = new HashSet<Encounter>();
            this.PokemonAbilities = new HashSet<PokemonAbilities>();
            this.PokemonForms = new HashSet<PokemonForms>();
            this.PokemonGameIndices = new HashSet<PokemonGameIndices>();
            this.PokemonItems = new HashSet<PokemonItems>();
            this.PokemonMoves = new HashSet<PokemonMoves>();
            this.PokemonStats = new HashSet<PokemonStats>();
            this.PokemonTypes = new HashSet<PokemonTypes>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> SpeciesId { get; set; }
        public long Height { get; set; }
        public long Weight { get; set; }
        public long BaseExperience { get; set; }
        public long Order { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Encounter> Encounters { get; set; }
        public virtual PokemonSpecies PokemonSpecies { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonAbilities> PokemonAbilities { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonForms> PokemonForms { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonGameIndices> PokemonGameIndices { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonItems> PokemonItems { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonMoves> PokemonMoves { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonStats> PokemonStats { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonTypes> PokemonTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That is my current Pokemon.cs file that was generated via T4. And this is my DbSet declaration inside PokeDBContext.cs:

`public virtual DbSet<Pokemon> Pokemon { get; set; }`

I'm getting the correct Intellisense since the classes are set up properly. I'm just getting an instant `InvalidOperationException` any time I try to access the entities. Note that the true Database entity is `pokemon.`

Comment: Why dont you consider using EF POCO at this link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

Comment: @Aravind That tool looks really awesome and seems like it should do exactly what I need. However, I keep running into issues when setting up my connection string. The connection string created by the EF Wizard is not working. I keep getting an error about `System.Data.EntityClient` provider failing to load. But it works for the normal transformations.

Comment: Nick. Please update your post with the error's screenshot along with corresponding code where error occurs

Comment: @Aravind I updated the question with my current errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but what you want is a simple snake case to PascalCase conversion. My concern is that EF would lose column mappings (if you're using model/database first) with these changes alone.

To do what you're asking, move your excellent CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name).Replace("_", ""); to a reusable method in the CodeStringGenerator class

```
public string PascalCase(string name)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name).Replace("_", "");
}
```

Then in the T4 template for the constructor change to:

```
public <#=code.Escape(codeStringGenerator.PascalCase(entity))#>()
{
<#
    foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
    {
#>
    this.<#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#> = <#=typeMapper.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
    }

    foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
    {
        // for readability hold the type name in a variable
        var typeName = typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
#>
    // pascal case here
    this.<#=code.Escape(codeStringGenerator.PascalCase(navigationProperty))#> = new HashSet<<#=code.Escape(codeStringGenerator.PascalCase(typeName))#>>();
<#
    }

    foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
    {
#>
    this.<#=code.Escape(complexProperty)#> = new <#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
    }
#>
}
```

Having done all this, your code will compile, but queries will likely fail due because the edmx still has the snake case naming, so no mappings to your actual database. Therefore, you'll also need to edit the edmx file. There are some examples here: [How to force pascal case with Oracle's Entity Framework support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694659/how-to-force-pascal-case-with-oracles-entity-framework-support), but at this point you start wondering if it's worth the effort.

**EDIT** Modifying the EDMX instead (better option)

First revert your T4 changes, you don't need them anymore. Then use the example in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069445/474702). I've modified it slightly to use your title case. I will be using this for a similar task:

```
// In the main method get your edmx/designer 
//EDMX File location
string pathFile = @"c:\Path\To\DbModel.edmx";
//Designer location for EF 5.0
string designFile = @"c:\Path\To\DbModel.edmx.diagram";
// ...
// replace the PascalCase method with this
public static string PascalCase(string name, bool sanitizeName = true, bool pluralize = false)
{

    // if pascal case exists
    // exit function

    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$");

    string pascalTest = name;

    if (name.Contains("."))
    {
        string[] test = new string[] { };
        test = name.Split('.');

        if (rgx.IsMatch(test[1].ToString()))
        {
            return name;
        }

    }
    else
    {

        if (rgx.IsMatch(name))
        {
            return name;
        }

    }

    //Check for dot notations in namespace
    string result;
    bool contains = false;
    string[] temp = new string[] { };
    var namespc = string.Empty;

    if (name.Contains("."))
    {
        contains = true;
        temp = name.Split('.');
        namespc = temp[0];

    }

    if (contains)
    {
        name = temp[1];
    }

    name = name.ToLowerInvariant(); // this may or may not be required
    // Here's the simplified snake to pascal case
    result = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name).Replace("_", "");

    if (contains)
    {
        result = namespc.ToString() + "." + result;
    }

    if (pluralize)
    {
        result = Pluralize(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe I ran into this exact issue. I had everything looking perfect. From my class names to my DbSets. It all looked exactly how I wanted it. But then I got an error about my entity not existing in the current context. It dawned on me all at once that LINQ to SQL was going to fail trying to find EntityX inside a DB with entity_x. I tried adding a Table annotation to each generated class, but that didn't seem to fix my issue. Any comments on getting LINQ to SQL to map appropriately? I *really* do not want to have to use snake case entities in C#.

Comment: You have edit the edmx file which contains the names to entities mapping in the EntitySetMapping elements. The question in the answer is one of a small number of examples addressing this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505088/entity-framework-capitalizing-first-property-name-letter), but they all involved either code first, or editing the edmx.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me out. I've updated my OP with some additional details regarding my `InvalidOperationException.` I searched inside the `.edmx` for where I might need to change the `EntitySetMapping` but it all looked like I expected it should. Any further comments?

Comment: Ok, for your question sorting out the constructor is addressed in the second block of code in the answer. Now, if you were to modify the EDMX instead, then you wouldn't even need to edit the T4 template!