# Lower-casing the query generated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, properties, ef-code-first

I need to lower case the column names while executing a function via Code First Entity Framework. I have tried to use the solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505088/entity-framework-capitalizing-first-property-name-letter) but it only works for table mapping and not for function mapping.

This is my POCO that holds the data from the function's execution.

```
 public class RBReportInfo
 {
     [Key]
     public int ReportId { get; set; }
     public int ReportDataViewId { get; set; }
 }
```

This is the code generated by EF where `fnrbreportinfo` is the function name and `@reportId` is the function parameter.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ReportId] AS [ReportId], 
[Extent1].[ReportDataViewId] AS [ReportDataViewId]
FROM [dbo].[fnrbreportinfo](@reportId) AS [Extent1]
```

The code below executes to populate the POCO.

```
var idParameter = new ObjectParameter("reportId", reportId);
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<RBReportInfo>(
            $"[{nameof(ReportBuilderContext)}].[fnrbreportinfo](@reportId)", idParameter);
```

This code is implemented in the `OnModelCreating()` method that changes the case of the properties to match the lower-case database column names in queries.

```
        modelBuilder.Properties().Configure(c =>
        { 
            var name = c.ClrPropertyInfo.Name.ToLower();
            c.HasColumnName(name);
        });
```

So, I want the query generated by EF to be as below where column names are in lower-case.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[reportid] AS [ReportId], 
[Extent1].[reportdataviewid] AS [ReportDataViewId]
FROM [dbo].[fnrbreportinfo](@reportId) AS [Extent1]
```

I have tried changing the property names to lower-case which works but it breaks the PascalCase convention for property naming in C#.

```
 public class RBReportInfo
 {
     [Key]
     public int reportid { get; set; }
     public int reportdataviewid { get; set; }
 }
```

I've also tried using the attributes but that failed too.

```
[Column("reportid")]
public int ReportId{get;set;}
```

The requirement is because of case-sensitive database due to which all the tables/functions will be in lower-case.

Comment: "The requirement is because of case-sensitive database due to which all the tables/functions will be in lower-case." Suggests that you aren't using SQL Server. Please state the Database engine and Entity Framework Provider which you are using. It sounds like the EF Provider (which is non-microsoft) has a bug in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried this but it looks promising for your case and i happen to be outside watching the maple leafs right now. EF allows interception so you can intercept the query and perhaps call `ToLower()` on the `command.CommandText`:

```
class EFCommandInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync,  command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContextt<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Intercepted on: {0} :- {1} ", command, commandText);
    }
}
```

You can read more [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't set attribute names instead of lover case naming properties?

```
[Table("mytable")]
public class MyTable {

    [Column("firstcolumn")]
    public int firstColumn {get;set}

    [Column("secondcolumn")]
    public string secondColumn {get;set;}

}
```

It's not a solution, but you can add custom methods like this

```
public IQueriable<TResult> SelectFromDB<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
{
        return source.SqlQuery(source.Select(selector).ToString().ToLower());
}
```

And then

```
using(var context = new DBContext())
{
    context.SomeTable.SelectFromDB(data => data).ToList();
}
```